# Mongodb $push query is very slow

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using the update query to push the document into the sub-document array. I have also added index for selector. But the query execution is very slow. Can anyone help me how can I increase the performance. This collection is having continuous update query execution like below.

My update query is below:

```
 db.title.update({
        "titleId": ObjectId("595625adbf50112535747c86"),
        "title": "Vintage"
     }, {
        "$push": {
            "source": {
                "value": 2008,
                "createdAt": ISODate("2017-06-30T10:19:00Z"),
                "user": ObjectId("5940dabcc5d9d01cf8666c87"),
            }
        }
     })
```

The index in db as below:

```
{
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "variable" : 1,
            "headerName" : 1
        },
        "name" : "titleId_1_title_1",
        "ns" : "XXXX.title,
        "safe" : true
    }
```

Comment: Why the compound index? What makes a document "unique" here? Surely just one of those fields is the actual unique value. Even if it's `"titleId"` then that's wasteful since the document already has a "unique" `_id` field anyway, so you are duplicating unique identifiers and wasting space in documents and an index. You don't use `"multi"` on the update so this must just be for one document at a time, therefore use the `_id` and remove the `"titleId"` from the document and remove the index you do not need. Also if any fields in `"source"` are indexed, then that will also need to be written.

Comment: I am having more than one document with same titleId but different title. The titleId is the foreign key of another collection document.